# How to understand notifies and subscribes in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to Chef. Recently I found the "notifies/subscribes" made me confused -- I think notifies should trigger another resource's action, and subscribes means a resource should be triggered by another resource. So I did a test, but it always run not as expected.
Here's my code --

My recipe--

```
file '/tmp/e.sh' do
    content '
#!/bin/bash
    
date +%F" "%T >> /tmp/e.log
'
    mode '777'
    notifies :run, 'execute[e.sh]', :delayed
end

execute 'e.sh' do
    command '/tmp/e.sh'
    subscribes :run, 'file[/tmp/e.sh]', :immediately
end
```

I think it should be -- once the "/tmp/e.sh" changed, then the "execute" resource of "e.sh" should be triggered, otherwise "/tmp/e.sh" should not run.
But to my surprise -- once the /tmp/e.sh modified(no matter changed from client side or workstation side), then the "execute" will run three times. And if the "/tmp/e.sh" unchanged -- the "execute" will run -- just only once.
I really messed up with this --

1. what does that "delayed" mean in "notifies" -- should it prevent the notified resource running?
2. what does that "subscribes" do? -- even the subscribed resouce didn't fire, and the resource itself still running?

   Please kind help. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notification system in Chef (`notifies` or `subscribes`) should satisfy your requirement of:

> once the "/tmp/e.sh" changed, then the "execute" resource of "e.sh" should be triggered, otherwise "/tmp/e.sh" should not run

All resources in Chef have a default action. This depends on the resource. The `file` resource  has a default action of `:create`. Whereas for `execute` resource, it is `:run`. The reason the `execute` resource is running every time is because its default action is `:run`.

All resources also have a `:nothing` action. This is also a [common functionality](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/). So when we use the notification system, we should use `action :nothing`.

Something like below:

```rb
file '/tmp/e.sh' do
  content "#!/bin/bash\ndate +%F" "%T >> /tmp/e.log"
  mode '0755'
end

execute '/tmp/e.sh' do
  action :nothing
  subscribes :run, 'file[/tmp/e.sh]', :immediately
end
```

You can use `notifies` or `subscribes`. Now the command execution will only happen with the `e.sh` file changed.

Coming to your questions...

> 1. what does that "delayed" mean in "notifies" -- should it prevent the notified resource running?

This is a timer for the notification. It defines when the "notified" resource should be run.

- `:immediately` - notify the resource to run immediately after, even if there are other resource declarations in between
- `:delayed` - notify the resource but run after all other resource declarations have been run (this is the default). This is useful when multiple resources could change, but we want to trigger the notification only once.

> 2. what does that "subscribes" do? -- even the subscribed resouce didn't fire, and the resource itself still running?

This does the opposite of `notifies`, i.e. it "listens" to changes in the specified resource.